# prevent "pretty" unicode emoji rendering in all browsers

Tags: css, firefox, unicode, cross-browser, emoji

I've seen many similar posts, but none appear to work (anymore at least, as of May 2019).

I'm trying to prevent Firefox minimally (Chrome seems fine atm) from rendering unicode characters as "pretty" emojis.

There are a lot of stack overflow posts; they say use Segoe font, or add a "modifier" character to force text rendering etc but these dont work in Firefox 67.0 atm. There are also suggestions to modify my browser configs. I'd be fine if that were just for me, but I'm trying to get a broad cross-browser, cross-OS solution. I've also seen suggestions to include the unicode as css `content` values in a pseudo-element, but that doesnt work either.

Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

here are some examples I tried in the last 5 minutes:

```html
<pre class="plain-emoji"></pre>
<pre></pre>
<span class="plain-emoji"></span>
<span class="test-emoji"></span>
```

```css
.plain-emoji {
  font-family: "Segoe UI","Segoe UI Symbol","serif","sans-serif";
}

.test-emoji::before {
  content: '\01F620';
  font-family: "Segoe UI Symbol";
}
```

with some other permutations... I've been trying anything that sounds reasonable...

thanks for your time in advance!